# routing in angular 12

Tags: angular, routes

I have used angular 12 in VSCode and Web Api 2 to develop my application.

my routing looks like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
     .......// other routes in the application
];

 @NgModule({
     imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
     exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I have deployed my application in Dev server. The url looks something like this

```
https://myDomain/MyApplicationFolder/Login
```

Login page is rendered perfectly. All the routing works fine. my only concern is

if I type

```
https://myDomain/MyApplicationFolder/  I get forbidden error.
```

[image]

Is there anyways that i get redirected to

```
https://myDomain/MyApplicationFolder/home
```

if anyone types

```
https://myDomain/MyApplicationFolder/
```

Comment: please define your application folder path in the `<base href="/MyApplicationFolder">` tag in index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems more of a problem with IIS, you should look into how you configured you server.

Is anonymous authentication on?

If you've configured an URL rewrite for this you could possibly rewrite the root path to /Home in IIS.

Comment: "URL rewrite h to /Home in IIS." did the trick. Thank You